# Presentation of a 3x3 categorical interaction for Cox proportional hazards regression using RMS package

Tags: r, regression, interaction, cox-model, rms

I wanted to verify my presentation of a 3x3 interaction of two categorical variables var1 (exposure of interest) and var2 (effect modifier of interest) using the `rms` package and `cph()` function in R.

Below is my basic code to set up the Cox proportional hazards regression model:

```
mod <- cph(Surv(follow.time, event) ~ var1 * var2 +, data = dataframe, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
Predict(mod, var1, var2=c('1','2','3'),ref.zero=TRUE, fun=exp)
```

The result after using `Predict()`is a single reference group with 8 other hazard ratio estimates. Is this correct approach to presenting a 3x3 interaction, using hazard ratios derived from a single reference category from `Predict()`?

### [image]

An alternative approach we considered was to take subgroups of var2 and run separate models for each. This seems to be most common in the literature. But we were advised that this would reduce the power of our model by reducing the sample to subsets. This approach would yield the table shown below:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first approach should be the most useful both to yourself and to your audience, provided that the proportional hazards (PH) assumption holds.

As you have been warned, reducing the data to a set of subset analyses (the second approach) loses power in the analysis as it cuts down on the number of cases whose information can be pooled in each analysis. The second approach also throws away information for the data presentation, for example, about how a change in `Var2` affects outcome at a constant level of `Var1` (e.g., at `Var1 = 1`).

You might need to adopt the second approach, however, if there were problems with the PH assumption in the combined interaction model. Even then, you would be better off with a single model stratified on one of `Var1` or `Var2`, allowing for different baseline hazard functions, plus interactions of the other predictor with those strata.